# Create a Child Test Plan under a Master Test Plan

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, test-plan

I am using Visual Studio 2016 with the latest updates. Though I am not the administrator of the project that I am working on, but I have access to creating as many number of Test Plans as required (though i can't delete them once created). I have already created a Master Test Plan, which has like 1000+ test cases, but then we do not need to run all of them everytime. So I was curious if I could create a child test plan under the Master one and  include the test cases that are necessary. I only get the green '+'when trying to create a test plan , but nothing to create the child ones.I didn't find any online guide either.
Is it actually possible to create one in VSTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot create the child test plan, it's not supported.

However you can create **Test Suites** under the test plan, then you can manage the test cases within the specific test suite.

Please see [Create a test plan and test suite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/manual-test/getting-started/create-a-test-plan) for detials.

And this article for your reference: [Test Planning and Management with Visual Studio Team Services](https://almvm.azurewebsites.net/labs/vsts/testmanagement/)

Comment: Not really resolved the issue, but just working with creating a new test plan each time (same level as the Master test plan) when there is a test pass.

Answer (score 0):

Test Plan is the highest group level for tests. What I often do is create a Test Plan for each sprint for example. So Test Plan Sprint 1 contains all the test cases that are applicable to this sprint. At the end of a sprint/start of a new sprint, you clone your current test plan and then modify it for the new sprint.

A Test Plan does not contain test cases directly (it's possible, just not recommended). Instead you use Test Suites to group the Test Cases. You have different types of Test Suites:

[image]

- Static: you manually add Test Cases to a static suite
- Requirement based: this allows you to create a suite that's linked to a Work Item. For example, you can define test cases that map to a Product Backlog Item that you're working on
- Query based suite: select test cases based on a query. For example, all high priority tests or all tests having a specific tag.

A Test Case can belong to multiple suites. You can nest other suites in a Static Suite.

So in your scenario, you have 1000 test cases that you want to group in suites. If this is a manual process, you can use a static test suite and just add existing test cases one by one until the suite meets your needs. If you can create a query that selects the test cases you want to work with you can use a query based suite.

I would recommend tagging your Test Cases with something like 'Ready For Test' (or another label that makes sense in your scenario) and then use a Query based suite. This is easier to maintain and probably less work. Especially if you use the Bulk Edit options to quickly add the tags.